# Using the GetElementByClassName and GetElementById

Tags: javascript, html

I want to print variables in the same paragraph but on different lines. I was using this:

```
<p id="demo1"></p><p id="demo2"></p><p id="demo3"></p>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try It!</button>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var lastname="Doe";
var age=30;
var job="carpenter";
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML=lastname;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML=age;
document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML=job;
}
</script>
```

but it prints each value in a new paragraph. I tried changing to classname instead but I'm doing something wrong. Help me please. TY.

```
<p class="demo1, demo2, demo3"></p>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try It!</button>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var lastname="Doe";
var age=30;
var job="carpenter";
document.getElementByClassName("demo1").innerHTML=lastname;
document.getElementByClassName("demo2").innerHTML=age;
document.getElementByClassName("demo3").innerHTML=job;
}
</script>
```

Also can you use

```
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML=lastname;
```

and more then one id and value at then end? Something like this?

```
document.getElementById("demo1,demo2,demo3").innerHTML=lastname,age,job;
```

How can you read that correctly, I know the above not valid, but what is the correct method to do it?

Ty
Jared Moore

Comment: Classes are space separated. You can't get more than one element by id . You can use `querySelectorAll('#demo1,#demo2,#demo3')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p id="demo1"></p>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Try It!</button>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var lastname="Doe";
var age=30;
var job="carpenter";
var concat = lastname + '<br />' + age + '<br />' + job
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML=concat;

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the three parts are in three different paragraphs is that you have three `p` elements. If you want all the values to be in the same paragraph, you should use an inline element, such as `span`. This is what it would look like:

```
<p><span id="demo1"></span><span id="demo2"></span><span id="demo3"></span></p>
```

By the way, using innerHTML is asking for someone to hack your site; if your real code looks anything like this:

```
element.innerHTML = userSuppliedData
```

then anyone can run whatever JavaScript they want on your page by passing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert('All your site are belong to us.');
</script>
```

This is known as cross-site scripting, XSS. Instead, do this:

```
element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(userSuppliedData))
```